# How do I get rid of the delimiters?

Tags: php, string, parsing

case 1:
I have a string **"57_5"**. How do i take out the **underscore(_)** which supposedly (i think) acts as a delimiter so that i may have **57** and **5**? The two values should be INTEGERS NOT STRING!!! I need to do this in PHP

case 2:
I have an **array ("57_8", "45_7", "24_3")**. I need to obtain each individual element in the array, take out the underscore then convert them into **INTEGERS**, so in total i should have 8 distinct values. How can this be achieved in PHP? I should have something like **57, 8, 45, 7, 24, 3** Remember the end result should NOT be an array and the values should be INTEGERS.

Comment: http://php.net/sscanf http://php.net/array_map http://php.net/closure - in short: You use existing functions for that which do part of the job. The whole thing (case 1+2) you do by programming. Depending on the quality you need you can also implode explode intval array_map all the things.

Comment: And beware of using CAPS ALL THE WAY :) - Online this is like screaming. I can understand you have a problem, but no reason/need to scream :D (I hope)

Comment: Oh and end result should not be array but integers is not easily possible without adding more information. If there are more than one integer, how should they be turned into a single integer (the integer type in PHP can only be a single integer, not multiple integers, that would be an array in PHP which you write you don't like)? By making a sum of all? Or are you looking for http://php.net/extract ?

Comment: Let's leave it with a comment. I mean your question wasn't the best either and I didn't downvote it as well so let's leave some wiggle room. And please fix the CAPS in your question.

Comment: Got it. I was just very upset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in comment, this is one variant, the *"implode explode intval array_map all the things"*:

```
$integers = array_map('intval', explode('_', implode('_', (array) $arrayOrString)));
```

- [Casting/Converting to array](http://php.net/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting)
- http://php.net/implode
- http://php.net/explode
- http://php.net/intval
- http://php.net/array_map

Thanks to the casting, this handles both cases at a time by normalizing the input.

Code-Example:

```
<?php
/**
 * How do I get rid of the delimiters?
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/18484012/367456
 */

$cases = [
    1 =>  "57_5",
    2 => array ("57_8", "45_7", "24_3"),
];

foreach ($cases as $num => $case)
{    
    $integers = array_map('intval', explode('_', implode('_', (array) $case)));
    echo 'Case #', $num, ': ', var_dump($integers), "\n";
}
```

Program Output:

```
Case #1: array(2) {
  [0]=> int(57)
  [1]=> int(5)
}

Case #2: array(6) {
  [0]=> int(57)
  [1]=> int(8)
  [2]=> int(45)
  [3]=> int(7)
  [4]=> int(24)
  [5]=> int(3)
}
```

See the [Online Demo](https://eval.in/45325).

Answer (score 0):

if you have a string that is 57_5 and take out the underscore u can do :

```
ex1=str_explode("_",$string);
```

And then you will have :

$ex1[0] will be 57 and $ex1[1] will be 5

Comment: There is no `str_explode` function in PHP.

Comment: It should be **explode($delimiter, $string)**, I appreciate the effort. I apologise for being a douche, Sorry